# Rails limit query after order and improve performance

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

*Sorry for the vague title*

I have a query where I'm getting a list of the 5 users with the highest `rating_number` which is an indexed column in the user table.

When I get the list of these users based on their `rating_number` then call the `.limit(5)` method, it will just take 5 users and then on those five users put them in order of rating_number, even though these users aren't the ones with the highest rating_number.

Here is the current scope, but I know I can improve the performance of this query so please let me know how to if you know, because I have a few of these queries on one page and it's performance is terrible.

in my user model

```
scope :top_five_users, -> do
  results = User.all
  results.order('rating_number DESC')
  results.limit(5)
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use `.all`

```
User.order('rating_number DESC')
```

Above is enough to obtain the highest rated users

And to limit 5 users

```
scope :top_five_users, -> do
  User.order('rating_number DESC').limit(5)
end
```

Comment: Yea that makes way more sense and I should have known that ha. Are there any other ways to improve the performance here?? I know using the rating_number as a counter_cached column has helped (im getting the count from another model) but would still like to improve even further.